# Why is assignment from string to char array missing the last character?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to insert the contents of a `std::string` to a char array. So I make a stringstream and do `getline` on it but for some reason the last character is missing from the array `a` when I print it. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "Hello, World";
   std::stringstream ss(str);

   char a[256];

   ss.getline(&a[0], str.length());

   std::cout << a; // "Hello, Worl"
}
```

Comment: Do you need an actual character array, or will something that can emulate one work? And are you using C++11?

Comment: The question was: 'why', not 'how to do it in a different way'.

Comment: @piokuc, Yes, but when you're stuck on doing it a certain way because you're almost there, it's still better to know how to do it more easily and effectively.

Comment: Please research `string::c_str()`, `string::substr()` and `string::data()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is because the second argument of `getline` is supposed to give the size of the buffer you are willing to give up and not the number of characters to extract. So in fact, the size includes the null character. You are saying that you want it to extract 12 characters (the length of the string) at most. Since we need to make room for the null character, of course we can only fit in one less than the whole string.

Really, you're supposed to use it like this:

```
ss.getline(a, 256);
```

The argument is the *maximum* number of `char`s it will possibly write to in the array, *not* the number of characters from the string you want to take. The number of characters it extracts is determined by the delimeter (which is `\n` in this case). You can, of course, make `256` whatever number of `char`s from `a` you want to allow it to write to. Just remember that it includes the null character.

Note that `&a[0]` is unnecessary. Arrays will undergo array-to-pointer conversion if need be.

Answer (score 2):

Check `getline` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline),
second argument specifies string size with null terminating character, so in your program you should use:
`ss.getline(&a[0], str.length() + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're passing a size of one too few to `getline()`, but there are better ways to do this. With C++11, you can emulate a modifiable character array (`std::string` has member functions for a non-modifiable one) by just using `std::string`:

```
std::string str = "Hello";
someFunc(&str[0], str.size());
```

Make sure, though, that `someFunc` does not overwrite the null character, even if it's with another null character. Pass the right size in to accommodate for that.

Without C++11, the easiest way is probably a vector:

```
std::string str = "Hello";
std::vector<char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
someFunc(&vec[0], vec.size());
```

Comment: this actually nowhere answers why the original code does not work as expected, as that is a specific property of the `stringstream.getline` interface, which is not even mentioned here.

Comment: @KillianDS, I mentioned it. There was already an answer with a great explanation of it at the time. My focus was on how to do it with a more robust method, which also happens to solve the problem, as `std::cout << &str[0];` in C++11 and `std::cout << &vec[0];` in C++03 will both output correct results. Anyway, I slightly clarified the first sentence to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `getline()` is the maximum number of characters to write to `a` (including the null character).